# SCCM Client Unable to Download from Software Centre

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-server-2012, sccm

I am getting the error below on all client computers when trying to install SCCM apps published to the software centre. This was working before Christmas, but not now and I don't know what or if any changes were made.

> The software change returned error code 0x87D00607(-2016410105).

When I google the error then it suggests checking the boundary groups. I have checked and my IP address of 10.201.8.44 is withing the configured boundary group which has a subnet id of 10.201.8.0. I can ping both the distribution point and the SCCM server.

I have checked the logs and can't see anything there that refers to the issue as after I get he error none of the client logs appear to change.

Can anyone advise what this could be?

I have since found the below entries in AppIntentEval.log:

```
<![LOG[ScopeId_491DD902-1680-4100-800B-8785AAF1F16F/DeploymentType_0d637f26-3f85-484b-8fcf-80b266342fc8/4 :- Current State = NotInstalled, Applicability = Applicable, ResolvedState = Available, ConfigureState = NotNeeded, Title = Office 365 Default Deployment Type]LOG]!>
<time="11:51:05.974+00" date="01-02-2019" component="AppIntentEval" context="" type="1" thread="8680" file="appconstructs.cpp:2847">
<![LOG[ScopeId_491DD902-1680-4100-800B-8785AAF1F16F/Application_49ae95ee-5afd-4b9d-8ec5-e0f4af338cba/5 :- Current State = NotInstalled, Applicability = Applicable, ResolvedState = Available, ConfigureState = NotNeeded, Title = Visio 2016]LOG]!>
<time="11:51:05.974+00" date="01-02-2019" component="AppIntentEval" context="" type="1" thread="8680" file="appconstructs.cpp:3553">
<![LOG[ScopeId_491DD902-1680-4100-800B-8785AAF1F16F/RequiredApplication_49ae95ee-5afd-4b9d-8ec5-e0f4af338cba/5 :- Current State = NonCompliant, Applicability = Applicable, ResolvedState = Compliant, ConfigureState = NotNeeded, Title = ApplicationIntentPolicy]LOG]!>
<time="11:51:05.974+00" date="01-02-2019" component="AppIntentEval" context="" type="1" thread="8680" file="appconstructs.cpp:4529">
```

Comment: The error refers to "content to found". Did you check whenever the content is available (physically) on the distribution points? Is there no even on either client or server available for that error?

Comment: I have tried redeploying one of the applications, it states that the content is available from now. This happens to all the published apps and some of these we know previously worked. I have found the entries below in the AppIntentEval.log file on the client:

Comment: See edit in main post for log entry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because rebooting resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rebooting the primary SCCM server resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Options in your Software Centre/ myITapps and then under computer maintenance allow for automatic install or unistall option. It will work

Comment: It seems strange to me that a running software that is failing to some extent will be affected by that setting.

Comment: I'm no longer working in the same job where I was working on SCCM. I did some training on it and had a better grasp of it. I think this was to do with the boundary group configuration and it needed to be changed to site instead of ip address ranges. Sorry, I can't remember it was a long time ago.